# java streamTokenizer parser

Tags: java, parsing

I have the following grammar:

```
gui ::=
    Window String widgets
widgets ::=
    Button STRING ';'|
    radio_button End ';'
radio_button ::=
    Radio String ';'
```

gui, widgets and radio_button are non-terminal. Others are terminal.

The statement I need to parse is:

Window "test" Radio "r1";

I use streamtokenizer in java to do the parsing. When it comes to widgets, I need to test the first line and then the second line. I use nextToken() to get the tokens of the statement. I want to save a copy of the tokenizer before I parse widgets so that if the first line fails, I can use the copy to parse the second line. How to save the copy?

Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `StreamTokenizer` has a method `pushBack` which restores the tokenizer's state so that you can call `nextToken()` again, without skipping the token not matched on the first try.

```
if( st.nextToken() == st.TT_WORD && "Button".equals( st.sval ){
    // deal with  Button STRING ';'
} else {
    st.pushBack();
    if( radioButton() ){  // call method to recognize Radio String ';'
        // handle End ;
        // ...
    } else {
        // error handling
    }
}


 boolean radioButton(){
     if( st.nextToken() == st.TT_WORD && "Radio".equals( st.sval ){
         // continue to match  String ';'
         // ...
         return true;
     } else {
         st.pushBack();
         return false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi @laune! The Javadoc for the `pushBack` method is : _"Causes the next call to the nextToken method of this tokenizer to return the current value in the ttype field, and not to modify the value in the nval or sval field."_ I don't really understand the "and not to modify the value in the nval or sval field". More simply, does it mean that calling "pushBack" moves back the Token pointer backward, so that calling "nextToken(); pushBack(); nextToken()" is equivalent to calling one time "nextToken()"?

Comment: These fields still contain what was stored after nextToken-ing what pushBack pushes back. Yes, to your Q.